# AzureAD Graph API - getting removed users using delta links on groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am not able to get **removed users** using a delta link retrieved from a previous call of https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta

Explanations:

1. I retrieve the groups using the query

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta

which returns the results correctly

Then I keep the delta link
(example of delta link from JSON response: `"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=7VBZ66f3HT ...`
)

2. I remove manually a user which belongs to a group to be sure the delta link works and returns the removed user id.

-> **nothing at all is returned**.

According to their documentation, it should work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#deltalink-response

Moreover, when i do the same thing with delta user query, it works fine, the removed user is returned with user delta link.

Question:

Does anyone is experiencing this issue and did you find any solution?

Comment: How much time are you allowing between the removal and the delta check? It may be a replication thing, try waiting up to 15 minutes.

Comment: @Zachafer no it does not change anything (waiting for more than 1 hour and the result is the same)

Comment: Any update for this issue? I was using security group. Have you tried to create a new goup?

Comment: @Tony Ju I have done a video to understand what i exactly do (groups are security groups and users are created manually)

Comment: I just noticed that you deleted the user directly. That's why you can only get removed user on user delta. If you remove the user from the group directly, you will get the removed user.

Comment: @Tony Ju I just tested it and you are right, I see the removed user only when the I remove it from the group: this behavior sounds very strange for me. If I delete  a member, the group delta does not detect this deletion ! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior. The documentation seems to suggest that a permanently deleted user should show up as @removed in groups delta query (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#deltalink-response)
- The first user in the list has been removed from the group - either by removing the membership or by deleting the user object itself. The "@removed" property describes that. Only users that have been permanently deleted are removed from groups".

Am I misinterpreting the statement? Logically, if a user is deleted all its group memberships should go away anyway.

Comment: @Illyr Did you find any alternate solution to find out the deleted users that belonged to a group?

Comment: @Urjit Did you find any alternate solution to find out the deleted users that belonged to a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your issue on my side. I am using [Microsoft graph explore](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test the api.

When I accessed the [final nextLink response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#final-nextlink-response), I got the deltaLink.

Then I removed two users from a group on Azure portal.

[image]

I can get the expected result when I access the deltaLink.

[image]

**Update:**

I just noticed that you deleted the user directly. That's why you can only get removed user on user delta. If you remove the user from the group directly, you will get the removed user.

Comment: I do not have the same results you have, i will post a video to exactly show what I do. (It probably depends on the group type or user type - there is something I do wrong but i do not know what it is) - groups are of security type (not Office365 type) and the users are created manually without any email.